# Is it possible to count how many cells containing single letters, hold a uppercase letter vs its lowercase version, without using named ranges?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Given a range of cells, each holding a single uppercase letter or its lowercase version, can I find out how many lowercase vs. uppercase characters there are, without using named ranges?

Like, A1 = "S", A2 = "s".

This CountIf both of them, so that doesn't work?

> =COUNTIF(A1:A2,"S")

While mixing SumProduct with Exact, seems to require Named Ranges, (calling A1:A2, "Letters".) which I don't want, since I want be able to know what I'm doing just by looking at my formulas.

I tried replacing Letters with {A1,A2}, but that doesn't seem to work?

> =SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT("D",Letters))

Comment: I can't see why would you need to use named ranges?? Maybe you could post some screenshots and the exact formula you've tried.

Comment: The solution is likely to be different depending on whether the value is a single character, as in your example.  Does your problem actually have just a single character per cell, or is this a simplified example?  Also, will every cell be guaranteed to contain one and only one character, which is a letter, or could there be empty cells, cells with numbers, etc.?

Comment: @fixer1234 - Single characters in cells... And every cell in the range has a letter... Gonna specify that...

Comment: @MátéJuhász - I just tried with an actual range A1:A2, instead of a list of cells, and it worked... I didn't know those were functionally different things... I might answer my own question, if no one else answers within a few days.

Comment: You have mixed up searchrange with criteria.

Comment: @JvdV - Why does it still seem to work fine? What cases make it fail?

Comment: What do you mean by that? What is failing?

Comment: @JvdV - It sounded like swapping searchrange and criteria would cause issues, but I haven't seen any. So, does it cause issues?

Comment: See my answer below for a correct result. You can't just swap parameters

Answer (score 3):

About your own formula; `=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT("D",Letters))`, you have mixed up the lookuprange with the criteria parameter, swap them around to `=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(Letters, "D"))`

[image]

If your goal was indeed to get the total of upper case and lower case I think what you were looking for was both the `UPPER` and `LOWER` functions?

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(EXACT(A1:A7,UPPER(A1:A7))))
```

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(EXACT(A1:A7,LOWER(A1:A7))))
```

Comment: Way better than mine.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you show testing for a specific uppercase or lowercase letter.  It wasn't clear whether that's your actual requirement or that's what you came up with as a first pass at a solution.  If you are testing for a specific character, it looks like you already have a solution.  If you want a more general solution, where you want to count all uppercase or all lowercase letters, you could use something like this:

[image]

Uppercase formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CODE(A1:A10)>64)*(CODE(A1:A10)<91))
```

Lowercase formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CODE(A1:A10)>96)*(CODE(A1:A10)<123))
```

This counts characters that fall into the uppercase or lowercase range of the ASCII table.  A named range isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

There are two formula in Excel that handles ASCII Character Set.

1. `=CHAR(Number)` which returns text eg. =CHAR(65) returns A.
2. `=CODE(Text)` which returns the ASCII Code eg. =CODE("A") returns 65.

So enter =CODE(A2) in Cell B2. You will get number 65 if letter is "A"(Capital) and Number 97 if letter is "a" (Small).

So Capital Letters have ASCII Code from Number 65 to 90 and small letters have ASCII Code from Number 97 to 122.

Once you get numeric Codes, you get your results by applying the formula

=(if B2 >=92, "Small", "Capital") etc.
Once you get Codes you can apply various Conditions to get the desired results.

Using all such Codes one can send Secret Documents by Changing the Codes by some amount say 13. Send the Documents and On Call give the COde is 13.

One can have complete list by writing Numbers 0 to 255 in Column A and entering formula
=CHAR(A2); Copy down the Column.

ASCII is 8 Bits Code. So it is up to 255.